# What is the recommended way to store default values for a class with many variants?

Tags: c++

I have a class that has several properties and the default property values change depending on a parameter.

Take for example we have a car class as below.

```
class Car {
    public:
        Car(int model);
        ~Car();

        int getFuelTankCapacity() const;
        void getTorque();
        void getCC();

    private:
        int fuelTankCapacity;
        int cc;
        int torque;
};
```

Assume we want to initialize the Car object based on the model number when created and assume there are 30 or more models. What is the right way to do? Should we have something like below?

```
Car::Car(int model)
{
    switch(model) {
        case swift:
            .....
        case rover:
            .....
    }
}
```

Or we should use factory class? I feel that factory class is not suitable as the models are too many. Any suggestions?

I just started working on C++ based project. Please forgive me and help.

Here is a slight variant of the above example. I saw only option to edit to add more info. Please suggest, if this is not correct.

Assume that we need to write an application for a range of mobile phones and want to have the same firmware. Assume all phones have the same processor and the difference is only in the interfacing devices like sensors, camera resolution, etc.

Assume that I am going to create classes for the proximity sensor, camera.

When booted, the application should get predefined capability based on the model(assuming the application can somehow fetch model). Once the model is known, it should initialize the objects with default values.

```
typedef enum _model_e {
    eMOB12MP,
    eMOB8MP,
    eLASTMODEL
};

typedef struct _camera_info_t {
    resolution_e res;
    ..........
}camera_info_t;

typedef struct _prox_sensor_t {
    bool supported;
    ........
}prox_sensor_t;

typedef struct _config_t {
    camera_info_t cam;
    prox_sensor_t prox;
    ....
}config_t;

static const config_t configs[] =
{
    { // model eMOB12MP
        .cam =
         {
            .res = 12MP,
            ........
         },
        .prox = 
         {
            .supported = false,
            ............
         },
         ........
    },
    { //eMOB8MP
        .cam =
        {
            .res = 8MP,
            ........
        },
        .prox =
        {
           .supported = true,
           ............
        },
        ........
    },
}

config_t *get_config(model_e model)
{
    config_t *ptr = NULL;

    if (model < eLASTMODEL && model >= 0) {
        ptr = configs[(int)model];
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

In the main function, I will call get_config() and initialize all the objects based on the config. The only reason the above approach is proposed because, whenever new model gets added which can be supported with the same firmware, changes needs to be done in one place. Is this correct?

Thanks,
Subbarao

Comment: One quick suggestion is to use an enum rather than an int to identify the model.

Comment: You should define some more classes, for each model one which derives from the base class. Start reading a c++ beginner book and look out for inheritance and virtual methods. You should not deal with if/switch in OOP designs to decide which type you have. In c++ a type ( swift, rover, ...) should be represented by by a c++ type ( class ). A factory is the correct solution and dealing with if/switch is never easier than dealing with more classes and a factory.

Comment: You probably want to make model a proper type of its own and delegate responsibilities to concrete instances. See Strategy pattern.

Comment: I agree with you. I had plans to use the enum. Did not come to mind while posting the query. Thanks for catching.

Comment: @Klaus IMHO what you describe is classic mistake: what a freshman would think to do after learning inheritance. Rule of thumb: you do not want to inherit when you can aggregate.

Comment: @Jon: A rover is still a car, so inheritance is ok. That did not mean that a car inherits from tires as here I agree it should build as aggregate.

Comment: Klaus, Many Thanks for the quick reply. I agree that I should use inheritance. I assume that this will apply even when there are several abstract classes like whose property vary based on the model.

Comment: @Klaus also, in the geometry domain a circle is an ellipse and a square is a rectangle. But in the programming language domain, if you inherit Circle from Ellipse etc you will quickly find out the hard way why that's a very bad idea. All of these examples are very well known, I invite you to give it more consideration. Cheers!

Comment: @VenkataSubbarao: From where come the `int model` ? is it known at compile time or not ?

Comment: @Jarod42: It is known at runtime. Assume we are burning the model number of EEPROM or flash.

Comment: Your `get_config` seems correct (except that it should return const pointer). I would do something similar.

Comment: [OT]: Note that `.cam =` is not standard C++ but an extension.

Comment: Looks to me likeike a builder pattern is best fit here..

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, .cam = is not standard C++. It is available only as part of C++11 or higher

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a use case for a [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). The example in wiki (PHP one, but still usefull to get the idea) even uses cars.

You could implement a variant which uses a register method, where you register your ~30 models in the factory. The factory then uses proper default values for creating your instance. These default values need to be given to the factory somewhere (most likely in a separate header file)

Comment: I agree that Factory Pattern could be an option. I am worried that the initialization code is spread across multiple classes. Also, is this efficient if the target hardware has very limited memory like 256MB? Is there any penalty if there are 4 to 5 classes, each of which needs to be derived 30 times ?

Comment: I can't tell about efficiency, as this deeply depends on the concrete implementation. However, 256mb is a lot of memory to use. You could tweak your compiler to optimize memory usage (mostly combined with slower execution). If you are worried about the initialization code.. well you need to write it somewhere. Maybe you can minimize the initialization process itself by finding common values? E.g. you initialize class B and C with the same values as A, etc

Comment: Another, more decentralized thing (your update is good, as It helps to understand your case better). I think of the devices holding their initialization data and sending them on request. This way they initialize themselves (more or less). If this is preferred, factory pattern is not the right thing